# How to open a DAL ( Django Autocomplete Light ) Select2 programmatically

Tags: javascript, django, jquery-select2, django-autocomplete-light

I'm using DAL to render an autocomplete from a form field like this:

```
    search = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=autocomplete.Select2(
            url='/search/my_search/',
            attrs={
                'data-placeholder': 'Select an option',
                'data-minimum-input-length': 1,
                'data-theme': 'bootstrap4',
            })
    )
```

It gets rendered with this class: "select2-hidden-accessible" and gets this attr "data-autocomplete-light-function="select2".
It doesn't get the "select2" class, that is given to one of its spans.
Everything works well, except that I can't open the select2 programmatically.

I tried:

```
 $('#id_search').select2('open')
```

But it gives the error: "The select2('open') method was called on an element that is not using Select2.", because DAL doesn't pass the class "select2" to the rendered form field "id_search".
Due to some peculiarities, I can't pass the class manually to the component.
If I click on the field, it opens and works normally.

I need some help in opening the select2 on page load.

Comment: Can you do `$('#id_search').addClass('select2').select2('open')`? Probably the quickest way to add the class you want. You may also need to call `.select2()` with no parameters first; I can't remember exactly how select2 works off-hand.

Comment: I've discovered that the error occurs because autocomplete.js isn't loaded yet on "$(document).ready()".
How can I know that it has been initialized?

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that the error is caused by autocomplete_light.js function initialize, that is tied to document.ready.
Trying to access the field.select2 on document.ready, doesn't work.
I need a way to focus and open the select2 on page load. Will post another question.